# Easy way to change ahref to radiobutton?

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, hyperlink

I have some code in oscommerce that makes the costumer able to view prices incl VAT or excl VAT with click on a text link.
I want to change the textlink to looks like this instead:

"Show prices [ X ] With VAT [  ] Excl VAT"
(where the [ ] is radiobuttons)

I have tried a few different solution i found on the web, but im not skilled enough. 
I hope someone can take a quick look and give me a hint? =)

```
<?php echo
'  <div>' .
'    ' . ((DISPLAY_PRICE_WITH_TAX == 'true') ? '<strong>' . TEXT_DISPLAYING_PRICES_WITH_TAX . '</strong>' : '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'action=toggle_tax&display_tax=true&uri='. urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) . '">' . TEXT_DISPLAY_PRICES_WITH_TAX . '</a>') . '' .
'    ' . ((DISPLAY_PRICE_WITH_TAX == 'false') ? '<strong>' . TEXT_DISPLAYING_PRICES_WITHOUT_TAX . '</strong>' : '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'action=toggle_tax&display_tax=false&uri='. urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) . '">' . TEXT_DISPLAY_PRICES_WITHOUT_TAX . '</a>') . 
'  </div>'?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. I don't understand what you're trying to do, and what you currently have (and what's wrong with it).

Comment: Sorry if im unclear. Today I have two text links - ahref. If I click on a link I change the way the shop displays taxes. (with the function "action=toggle_tax...etc". This solution dosent looks good. It looks like this: Show prices with taxes Show prices without taxes. That look isnt what i want. I want it to look like ""Show prices [ X ] With VAT [ ] Excl VAT"  where the change of radio button will call the function "action=toggle..."

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, then you want to allow the user to show prices with/without tax.

One possibility is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a JavaScript library.

If you decide to go this route, you can have each price printed out to the page, but hide the prices the user doesn't want to see.

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Include the jQuery Library via CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Display Prices, hide one -->
<div class="with_vat">$xxx</div>
<div class="without_vat" style="display:none">$yyy</div>

<!-- Options -->
<input type="radio" name="vat_choice" value="1" checked />  Show Vat
<input type="radio" name="vat_choice" value="0" />  Exclude Vat

<!-- jQuery to Hide/Show the divs when radio is changed -->
<script>
$("input[name='vat_choice']").change(function(){

  // Get Value
  var vatChoice = $(this).val();

  if(vatChoice == 1){

    $('.with_vat').show();
    $('.without_vat').hide();

  }
  else{

    $('.with_vat').hide();
    $('.without_vat').show();

  }

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

You can see the code in action, here: http://jsfiddle.net/PKh3y/.

You could also achieve your desired result by redirecting when a radio button is clicked.  The solution below does use (a little bit of) PHP.

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- Include the jQuery Library via CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Display Prices depending on $_GET parameters -->
<?php if(!isset($_GET['without_vat'])): ?>
<div class="with_vat">$xxx</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="without_vat">$yyy</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Options -->
<input type="radio" name="vat_choice" value="1" checked />  Show Vat
<input type="radio" name="vat_choice" value="0" />  Exclude Vat

<!-- jQuery to redirect when radio is changed -->
<script>
$("input[name='vat_choice']").change(function(){

  // Get Value
  var vatChoice = $(this).val();

  if(vatChoice == 1){

     window.location = 'http://example.com/';

  }
  else{

    window.location = 'http://example.com/?without_vat=1';

  }

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I hope that answers your question, good luck!

Comment: Just curious, did this answer your question?  I can provide more assistance if not.